Setting Up Java Exception Handling for My Program
I was trying to handle some exceptions in my code for the prime number detector I am working on. This is my current code:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Frame1 {
  private JFrame frame;
  private JPanel panel;
  private JTextField textField;
  private JLabel label;
  private JButton button;
  private JLabel DisplayLabel;
  private JPanel DisplayPanel;

public Frame1() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Prime Detector");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(420, 420);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

    label = new JLabel("Enter a number");
    label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
    panel.add(label);


    DisplayPanel = new JPanel();
    DisplayPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    DisplayPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    DisplayPanel.setVisible(false);

    DisplayLabel = new JLabel();
    DisplayLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 30));


    textField = createJTextField();
    panel.add(textField);

    button = new JButton("Enter");
    button.setFocusable(false);
    button.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    button.setForeground(Color.cyan);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TheCode code = new TheCode();
            BigInteger number = new BigInteger(textField.getText());
            try{
            code.primeDetector(number);


            if (TheCode.IsItPrime) {
                DisplayLabel.setText(number + " is prime.");
                DisplayLabel.setVisible(true);
                DisplayPanel.setVisible(true);
                DisplayPanel.add(DisplayLabel);
            } else {
                DisplayLabel.setText(number + " isn't prime.");
                DisplayLabel.setVisible(true);
                DisplayPanel.setVisible(true);
                DisplayPanel.add(DisplayLabel);
                }
            }catch(Exception exception){
             DisplayLabel.setText("Enter a Valid Number");
            }
        }
    });

    panel.add(button);

    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(DisplayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}


public void show() {
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private JTextField createJTextField() {
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);

    return textField;

   }
}

However, when I run this code and try to enter something invalid it still shows the red exception message in the console which is what I am trying to prevent. Can someone help me? (By the way the primeDetector method and TheCode class are well defined and working as should)

seems like BigInteger constructor would throw there.  Are you seeing ArithmeticException?

No, Whenever I type something invalid in the text box it's supposed to catch a NumberFormatException and show Enter a Valid Number in the UI. However it doesn't show that and instead shows an exception message in the console which I don't want.

    BigInteger number = new BigInteger(textField.getText());
    try{
        code.primeDetector(number);

The issue here is that the BigInteger construction is not inside the try block, so it won't be handled by the corresponding catch block. So it should be moved in.
    try{
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(textField.getText());
        code.primeDetector(number);


Thanks, I did that and my code worked.
